# Jconsole live threads count and java ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice, jconsole

Monitoring our app using JConsole over a period of time shows that the “live thread” count is increasing constantly. Increasing thread count sounds like a bad thing to me, or am I wrong?

Synopsis:
In our app we create thread pools for various collectors using Executors.newFixedThreadPool, Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor. These collectors are called every few minutes. 
And there is this  other service which is called n times by the above collectors during every collection. This service generates a single thread (Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);) that executes a FutureTask. For all the above ExecutorServices  we call shutdownNow() only if an exception is caught and leave the rest for GC.

1)  Do I need to shutdown the executors once the process is finished or can I rely on GC?

Thanks for your suggestions and insights
Ajju

Comment: did you find either answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

One should call shutdown explicitly on executor service - executor.shutdown() for orderly shutdown & reclamation of resources (old tasks are executed while new ones are not accepted).

shutdownNow() attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution (there is no guarantee about the executing tasks - they may or may not execute - this is a best attempt).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

We use shutdownNow() for similar purpose, to stop all executing process.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a thread pool is to avoid the overhead of spawning new threads during processing. You are NOT supposed to spawn new thread *pools* ! (Which is what you're doing here `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);`)

You should set up your thread pools when your application starts, and inject them into your processing objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I see your point and will try for a solution towards it.